# MVC 4 - many to many - get data only gets id of related table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, many-to-many

Adding new data to the database is working with the many to many relationship.

Now I'm trying to get the project with all categories (category includes id and name). When I get all the project from my database then the associated categories are filled in, but only the id's.

### CLASSES

```
public class Project
{
    public Project() {
        Categories = new HashSet<Category>();
    }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Titel")]
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}


public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

### CONTEXT

```
        /*************ProjectS**************/
        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasKey(t => t.ProjectID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().ToTable("Project", "freelauncher");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Property(t => t.ProjectID).HasColumnName("project_id").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasMany(p => p.Categories)
            .WithMany(cat => cat.Projects)
            .Map(pc =>
                {
                    pc.ToTable("category_has_project");
                    pc.MapLeftKey("project_id");
                    pc.MapRightKey("category_id");
                }
        );


        /*************CATEGORY**************/
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasKey(t => t.CategoryID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().ToTable("category", "freelauncher");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().Property(t => t.CategoryID).HasColumnName("category_id");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().Property(t => t.CategoryName).HasColumnName("category_name");
```

### CONTROLLER

```
    public ActionResult Projects() 
    {
        IEnumerable<Project> projects = Adapter.ProjectRepository.Get();
        return View();
    }
```

### REPOSITORY

```
    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong to get the CategoryName in my projects?

[image]

Comment: Might be a silly question but is the CategoryName property definitely set for all your categories?

I copied and pasted your code into a new visual studio solution, added a couple of categories to the db and it worked perfectly for me.

The category property on each project is populated with a full category complete with its CategoryID and CategoryName

Comment: Yes, all categories are filled... The many to many relationship has 3 tables ofcourse - Project - Category AND project_has_category. It seems like the categories are loaded from the table project_has_category, but not filling in the categoryName...

Comment: @Rik Leigh, you are right... All categories were filled in when i forwarded my database to phpmyadmin. When I save the project with the corresponding categories, than the category names are deleted from my database. Now I'm searching how this can possibly be deleted. Thx for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works perfectly, the Category Names were missing from the db. (see comment above)